# Trouble with Python and IntelliJ

Tags: python, intellij-idea, flask

I'm writing a Flask application in IntelliJ, and for some reason I can't get IntelliJ to recognize Flask extensions. And so this works just fine:

```
from flask import Flask, Response, request
```

But this does not:

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
```

It will recognize and autocomplete `flask.ext` but not any submodules.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

More info:

- I'm using virtualenv and installing dependencies via `bin/pip install <dependency>`.
- I'm using the Python 2.7.5 SDK
- The modules that I'm trying to get IntelliJ to recognize have all been successfully installed.

Comment: have you tried `from flask_wtf import Form`? I'm not sure the reason, but this is how it is for me in PyCharm

Comment: @Nathaniel That indeed did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyCharm has difficulty completing `flask.ext...` because all `flask.ext` does is proxy imports at runtime, so the built-in static detection is faulty.

For future reference, `flask.ext` is deprecated in favor of using the actual package import such as `from flask_wtf import Form`. As of Flask 1.0 it has been removed completely.